# Font: howto configure pixel font correctly on linux?

Tags: linux, fonts, arch-linux, fontconfig

I followed this guide and its subpixel rendering topic: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/font_configuration#Pixel_alignment

But still can't achieve the same appearance result to pixel font ProggyCleanTT on windows 10 (picture from wsl - windows subsystem linux, size 12)

[image]

How to configure pixel font correctly on linux/archlinux that has similar appearance as on windows 10?

Comment: Is this screenshot supposed to show the "desired" appearance from Windows, or the "bad" appearance from Linux? (If it's supposed to be a pixel font, that screenshot looks horrible – almost as if it's being stretched to a font size that it wasn't created for.)

Comment: It's desired one, I find it pretty comfort to work with, because it's pixel so it tends to hard to see. @grawity

Comment: Well, I think it could be achieved, but it seems like it's a different question: you're asking how to deliberately configure a pixel font _incorrectly_ (to make it look blurry and almost like a non-pixel font). Do you have a screenshot of what it currently looks on Linux? Are you using Arch's standard freetype?

Comment: Yes, I use freetype2 2.9.1-1 - should be latest in arch repo, also aur/freetype2-cleartype that enable cleartype subpixel rendering. I'll attach it once I've got home. @grawity